# paypal payment gateway integration

Tags: php, paypal

I am integrating paypal payment gateway in one of site.After successful payment i am redirecting it to `success.php` file. In `success.php` file i have included all the insert parameters and a success message. It is redirecting to `success.php` file properly after making payment but showing payment failed message and no data is inserting to the database. following is my `success.php` page code

```
<?php
 include 'dbConfig.php';


//Get payment information from PayPal
$item_number = $_GET['item_number']; 
$txn_id = $_GET['tx'];
$payment_gross = $_GET['amt'];
$currency_code = $_GET['cc'];
$payment_status = $_GET['st'];

//Get product price from database
 $productResult = $db->query("SELECT price FROM products WHERE id = = '".$item_number."'"); 
$productRow = $productResult->fetch_assoc();
$productPrice = $productRow['price'];

if(!empty($txn_id) && $payment_gross == $productPrice){
//Check if payment data exists with the same TXN ID.
$prevPaymentResult = $db->query("SELECT payment_id FROM payments WHERE txn_id = '".$txn_id."'");

if($prevPaymentResult->num_rows > 0){
    $paymentRow = $prevPaymentResult->fetch_assoc();
    $last_insert_id = $paymentRow['payment_id'];
}else{
    //Insert tansaction data into the database
    $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO   payments(item_number,txn_id,payment_gross,currency_code,payment_status) VALUES('".$item_number."','".$txn_id."','".$payment_gross."','".$currency_code."','".$payment_status."')");
    $last_insert_id = $db->insert_id;
}
 ?>
<h1>Your payment has been successful.</h1>
<h1>Your Payment ID - <?php echo $last_insert_id; ?></h1>
<?php }else{ ?>
<h1>Your payment has failed.</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: No prepared statements for one. You're [wide open to SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo/2685/preventing-sql-injection-with-parametrized-queries)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Van Hoa, paypal does not send payment information as parameters when you redirect a user to your success page.  PayPal will only send back a token and a payer ID.

> When redirecting the buyer back to your website from paypal.com,
> PayPal appends the Express Checkout transaction token and the unique
> PayPal buyer ID as GET parameters to your RETURN URL;
> these GET parameters are named **token** and **PayerID**.

[PayPal docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReference/#id084RN0V0QRO) (emphasis added)

You can use the returned token to get the payment details using `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` and passing it the token you get back from PayPal.